# weak convergence lim inf sequence example

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, numerical-methods, weak-convergence

I have been stumped by the following problem , I was able to answer the first part of the problem which involved the inequality by using weak convergence. But when it came to looking for such an example as that does applies to the question above I was not able to fully formulate the procedure. 
I believe I can construct a sequence made up of two subsequences where one diverges to +$\infty$ and the other one converges to $0$. However I am not entirely sure if this is the right method of approaching the problem.

The way the problem is stated is as such,
 If $\{u_n\} \rightharpoonup \{u\}$, then $$ ||u||\le \lim_{n\to \infty} inf ||u_n||.$$ Show by example that in general, $$ ||u|| \neq \lim_{n\to \infty} inf ||u_n||.$$

Comment: What is the relation between $u$ and $(u_n)$??

Comment: In your title you talk about weak convergence, but in the question you seem to be talking about sequences of numbers? What is the question about?

Comment: This question is in serious need of restating. What is the norm, what space are we in, etc.

Comment: I have rewritten the question as to the way it was asked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While the text of the question does not make a lot of sense, I will answer based on the tags and the title.

In a Banach space $X$, it is possible to have a sequence $\{u_n\}$ with $u_n\to u$ weakly, and $\|u\|<\liminf\|u_n\|$.

For instance, let $X=\ell^2(\mathbb N)$, and $u_n=\delta_n$ (i.e. $u_n=(0,\ldots,0,1,0,\ldots)$ with the $1$ in the $n^{\rm th}$ place). Then $u_n\to0$ weakly, while $\|u_n\|=1$ for all $n$.

Comment: I have rewritten the question as it was stated, does the question make more sense?

Comment: Not really, sorry.   You are not stating what kind of space you are considering,  and your examples show that you don't seem to understand what the element of your space are.

Comment: Yes exactly that is where I was mainly confused in, and what I believed to be a possible approach in answering the question. But after I have seen your post I understand why the dirac delta functions follows the criteria $||u|| < \lim_{n\to \infty} inf||u_n||$. However I was wondering if perhaps there are different sequences that may follow the same criteria?

Comment: Of course. In the classic Banach spaces where the elements are given by sequences, weak convergence means roughly to ignore the first coordinates of the vector; this can be done in many ways that do not decrease the norm.